# Javascript function have sub functions / variables

Tags: javascript, function, object

This is the working code:

```
var test = function ()
{
    console.log(test.data);
};

test.data = 'hello';

test.set = function (data)
{
    test.data = data;
};

test.set('Test');
test();
```

This outputs `Test` to my javascript console.
Now I was wondering, if there was a way to do it using something like this?

```
var test = {
    this: function ()
    {
        console.log(test.data);
    },

    data: 'hello',

    set: function (data)
    {
        test.data = data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Functions are objects, but objects are not functions. Of course you can store functions as object properties but you can't make a plain object "callable". Or what do you actually want to achieve? What should be the advantage of your second approach?

Comment: I want to call function test.this() by using just test()

Comment: @Felix I believe you're missing the point - I think he's trying to encapsulate all the information, and just having a neater/more organised approach.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do.

Comment: I wish JavaScript could do this too!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I have written in my comment, you cannot make an object "callable". You can however automate the process from your first example:

```
function extend(func, props) {
    for(var prop in props) {
        if(props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            func[prop] = props[prop];
        }
    }
    return func;
}
```

and then call it with:

```
var test = extend(function(){
    console.log(test.data);
},
{
    data: 'hello',    
    set: function (data) {
        this.data = data;   // note that I changed it to `this.data`
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fGXGH/)

---

That said, I think you should not use functions like that. It will be easier to understand if you just have a "normal" object and call every method with `obj.method()` instead of having `obj()`.

At least you have to document this very carefully.

Comment: Where's the `hasOwnProperty` call? ;)

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: Well I assumed one would pass only plain objects anyway... but yes... extension of `Object.prototype` ... bla bla... (I hope one day they make the built in prototypes **not** extendable!)... fixed :)

Comment: That would a great thing, but I doubt they will ever do that :/

Answer (score 4):

How about doing something like this:

```
function Test () {
  this.data = 'hello';
  this.set = function (data)
    {
        test.data = data;
    }
  this.log = function ()
    {
        console.log(test.data);
    }
}

var test = new Test ();
test.set('Test');
test.log();
```

This has the advantage you can create new instances easily.

---

If you just want a one-off, I would say your own suggestion is almost what you want:

```
var test = {
    log: function ()
    {
        console.log(test.data);
    },

    data: 'hello',

    set: function (data)
    {
        test.data = data;
    }
};

test.set('Test');
test.log();
```

But perhaps your question was how to avoid the ".log" part?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid that ".log" part.

Comment: So you want the log to essentially be in a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You can store any functions under properties in your object. And you can invoke them:

```
let f = { fun1: function () 
                {
                     return 1; 
                } 
        };
f.fun1();
```

is going to work perfectly. I am not sure if you can use 'this' as a property name as it is a keyword. Probably no problem with that, but it might be misleading.