# Delay-execute any existing function by a call of the form "function_name.callAfter(ms, param1, param2, ...)"

Tags: javascript, delay, delayed-execution

I recently got an interview question, that I failed to answer correctly. Here it goes:

> Write an implementation of a function `callAfter` that enables ANY function to be called after some specified duration. The output of the function should remain the same. The function should have > following syntax:
>
> **Example 1:** Let's say you have a function called `sum` like so:
>
> ```
> function sum(a, b) {
>  console.log('Sum is: ', a + b);
> }
> ```
>
> Now you should be able to execute:
>
> ```
> sum.callAfter(5000, 8, 9);
> ```
>
> This should invoke the function `sum` after 5 seconds with parameters 8 and 9. 
>   Output: 'Sum is: 17'.
>
> **Example 2:** For a function `difference` with the following implementation:
>
> ```
> function difference(a, b) {
>   console.log('Difference is: ', a-b);
> }
> ```
>
> You should be able to execute:
>
> ```
> difference.callAfter(4000, 8, 6);
> ```
>
> This should invoke the function `difference` after 4 seconds with parameters 8 and 6. 
>   Output: 'Difference is: 2'.

NOTE: I am aware that I could execute a function after n seconds using something like:

```
var delay_func = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

However, I was asked to attach a `callAfter` *'sub-function'* with every function to facilitate the call:

```
<function_name>.callAfter(milliseconds, param1, param2, ...);
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4906748/9201277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a method to the function constructor's prototype object. That way any created function can inherit that method. It's referred to as [prototypal inheritance](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9):

```
Function.prototype.callAfter = function(delay, ...args) {
    setTimeout(() => this(...args), delay)
};
```

Answer (score 5):

We know if we add a function to `Function.prototype` it is callable on all functions.
So we use this code:

```
Function.prototype.callAfter = function (time, ...params) {
  setTimeout(this(...params), time);
}
```

Now any function that defined has the `callAfter` method.

For example:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  console.log('Sum is: ', a + b);
}

sum.callAfter(500, 3, 2) // output => Sum is: 5
```

Or:

```
function difference(a, b) {
  console.log('Difference is: ', a-b);
}

difference.callAfter(500, 3, 2) // output => Difference is: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understood the task you should use [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).
The function prototype helps you to implement the function that will be able to use for every function where your code attached.

```
Function.prototype.callAfter = function(delay = 4, arg1, arg2) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return  this.call(null,  arg1, arg2);
    }, delay)}


function summ ( arg1, arg2){
    console.log('summ',  arg1 + arg2);};


summ.callAfter(500, 5,6)
```